# How C char is different from C++ string element accessed using index

Tags: c++, string, stl

I am using C++ erase remove idiom and facing a weird problem.
If I access element using string index result is not as expected.

```
   string str = "A man, a plan, a canal: Panama";
   str.erase(remove(str.begin(), str.end(), str[1]), str.end());
```

**Result : Aman, a plan, a canal: Panaa**

and if I use as below, result is as expected.

```
   string str = "A man, a plan, a canal: Panama";
   str.erase(remove(str.begin(), str.end(), ' '), str.end());
```

**Result : Aman,aplan,acanal:Panama**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the signature of `std::remove`:

```cpp
template< class ForwardIt, class T >
ForwardIt remove( ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, const T& value );
```

The `value` is passed by const reference, therefore after removing first space your `str[1]` points to a wrong memory. It's unsafe to access container elements while modifying the container.

Comment: And a solution is to pass `static_cast<char>(str[1])` or assign `str[1]` to a variable of type `char` beforehand.

Comment: @Thomas Good idea; I much prefer the second approach.  I see that Vlad also has a neat (if slightly obscure) alternative.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm `std::remove` is declared the following way

```
template<class ForwardIterator, class T>
ForwardIterator remove(
    ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last,
    const T& value // <-- reference!
);
```

As you can see the third parameter is declared as a reference `const T& value`.

So in this call

```
str.erase(remove(str.begin(), str.end(), str[1]), str.end());
```

the third argument is a reference to the object `str[1]` the value of which is changed within the algorithm to the letter `'m'` when the first character `' '` is encountered..

If you would write for example

```
str.erase(remove(str.begin(), str.end(), str[1] + 0), str.end());
```

you would get the expected result because in this case the reference refers to a temporary object.